# Open a div after clicking on first checkbox using Angular Js 1.5.0

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope

I am new, trying my hands on angular. I made a list of checkbox using ng-repeat, there are five checkboxes and want to open a div only clicking on first checkbox. Don't know how to open.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pIngPpDECeXWQdmGBvb5)

[image]

Thank you all in advance...

Comment: Please create a plunker for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the model with checkbox and can toggle the display of the div based on the model value of the desired checkbox. I have created one plnkr for same: http://plnkr.co/edit/zcHbuwsUehDfBkgJWlIc?p=preview

HTML code

```
//HTML
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example12-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div ng-repeat="cb in chkboxArr">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkboxArrModel[$index]">{{$index}}
  </div>

  <div ng-if="chkboxArrModel[0]">Toggle me with first checkbox</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Javascript code

```
//JS

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.chkboxArr = [1,2,3,4];
    $scope.chkboxArrModel = [];
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div like this:

```
<div ng-show="ModelData.Passengers == 'One'">
    The actual div content you have in the div you want.
</div>
```

Assuming your radio buttons code to be like this:

```
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" id="PassengersId1" name="PassengersName1" ng-model="ModelData.Passengers" value="One" />One
          <input type="radio" id="PassengersId2" name="PassengersName2" ng-model="ModelData.Passengers" value="Two" />Two
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Those are radio buttons, not checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<div ng-show="checkbox1">Show me</div>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox2" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox3" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

is it possible to make using ng-repeat like below code:-

 <li ng-repeat="items in shareList">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{items.name}}" name="{{items.name}}" id="{{items.name}}" />
        <label for="{{items.name}}">{{items.name}} </label>
      </li>

Instead making them separately:-

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox2" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox3" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
         <div ng-show="chk1">Div1</div>

         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk1"/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation.